# No reply URL Configured Microsoft Azure API

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I'm working on a class project to help my teachers for teams meeting and I am facing some issues so need a bit of suggestion.

In mscore-graph-python api project on github what is the expected redirect url which should be created in app registration? or in azure api i guess that is the one.

I get an error right when I give consent to the application.

`Message: AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.`

I enabled the default URL in the authentication section of the application. Any suggestion what's wrong here.

Current URL where i get error is
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/Consent/Set`

once i login in even successfully something is going wrong either in middle ware and i am not able to get the url or maybe my redirecct URL is wrong.

I also tried the default url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient` but i also gave an error

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'e2ab39bb-a046-4957-90ba-1295e26dac89'.
```

I even tried to set it to default but even that's not working. So need a bit of suggestions for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it i decoded the URL and it was expecting a redirect URL http://localhost:8400 through middleware.